# Searching in multiple tables using MS SQL Server 2000

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, search, sql-server-2000, asp.net-2.0

We have a database with a lot of information about Persons. I won't post the entire database structure because it is too big, but it looks something like this:

---

**Person**
ID
Name
Street
City
State
Country

**Language**
LangCode
Language

**Interest**
ID
LastChangedBy
LastChangedOn

**LocalizedInterest**
InterestID
LangCode
Description

**PersonInterest**
PersonID
InterestID

---

Now, this is just a small example. In our database, we have about 8-9 localized tables (like Interest) a Person can be linked to. A Person can have multiple Interests, a Person can have multiple Jobs, a Person can have multiple Educations, a Person can have multiple Experiences, ...

I have to build a search function. Let's say you enter "tom" as the search term. This should give a list of all Persons with "tom" in their Name, Street, City, State, Country, in one of their Interests, in one of their Jobs, in one of their Educations, in one of their Experiences or in one of the other linked tables.

If you enter multiple words to search for (eg. "tom php"), it should give a list of all Persons with "tom" in their Name, Street, City, State, Country, in one of their Interests, in one of their Jobs, in one of their Educations, in one of their Experiences or in one of the other linked tables **AND** "php" in their Name, Street, City, State, Country, in one of their Interests, in one of their Jobs, in one of their Educations, in one of their Experiences or in one of the other linked tables.

At the moment there are about 4,500 records in the Person table and if I do an outer join of Person with all the tables I have to search, there are about 1,300,000 records and 40-50 fields to search in.

How should I approach this problem so that performance will be acceptable? The client expects "something like Google" in terms of speed and ease of use.

We're using MS SQL Server 2000 and ASP.NET 2.0. The search functionality has to be added to an existing application and changing the technology or database structure is not an option.

Comment: sounds like a case for an indexed view, searched upon by a stored proc. is adding an indexed view an "option"? youre not really changing the structure.

Comment: I think we would have to use outer joins to build that view (a person still has to be found when he has no Jobs or Interests) and you can't put an index on a view with outer joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement full-text search in involved tables/fields and then create a query based on it. You can find quick info [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20010422.asp).

Comment: Thanks. We'll give this a try.

Comment: Our database is running on a shared server so unfortunately we cannot use full text indexing.